# Can I exclude auto-generated files from a pull request in GitHub?

Tags: c#, .net, git, github, specflow

Some pull request can get pretty large and often and I'd like to minimize noise for my team members that will be reviewing and merging my pull requests by removing auto-generated files.

For example, `.feature.cs` file types created by Specflow.

Edit: To be clear, those files still need to be merged, I'd just like to remove them from the reviewing process.

Comment: Auto-generated files often shouldn't be in your repository to begin with. But if you need them to be tracked, and you need to merge them, then they're part of the merge and therefore show up in the merge request.

Comment: Are you merging across repos or within branches in the same repository?

Answer (score 1):

The other option is not to commit them at all and have the regenerated as part of the build process. See [this](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild) for details of how to integrate specflow file generation into msbuild process

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove these auto-generated files from the review process, I suggest you put them into separate commits from your manual changes and to give them a special comment that identifies them to your team as commits not to be reviewed. Then you will be able to take them out of your review workflow, but not out of the pull request.

I use the [Git Source Control Provider](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c) which allows for easy cherry-picking of files to include in each commit, which would make separating these changes into "auto generated" commits trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post an update in 2024 because it seems possible already (at least to a degree).

GitHub will respect it if you mark some files as auto-generated in `.gitattributes`, e.g.:

```
some-folder/*.* linguist-generated=true
```

Such files will render in the UI as collapsed by default, and the message will hint that they are autogenerated. Example screenshot ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55820894/889779)):

[image: GitHub's PR view for auto-generated files]

Official docs: https://github.com/github-linguist/linguist/blob/master/docs/overrides.md