# GitHub not enforcing .gitattributes when local git repo does

Tags: git, github

I have added a `.gitattributes` file in the root of my git repository. I have specified `-diff` for JSON files and split tar.gz files i created. This is what my `.gitattributes` file look likes:

```
my_sub_directory/archive.tar.gz.part.* -diff linguist-generated=true
*.json -diff linguist-generated=true
```

With the `.gitattributes` file, I am aiming to tell git to treat JSON files and these archives as binaries so it doesn't track number of lines from them. My local git repo seemed to have successfully picked it up and treats the files as binaries. However, when i try merging it to my remote master GitHub repository, the merge request treats archives as text files and counts their lines, which tells me that it is disregarding the included `.gitattributes` file.

I thought it could be that GitHub uses the `.gitattributes` that is already on master. So, I have committed the `.gitattributes` file to master separately before trying to merge in the JSON files and the archives. But GitHub still treats the files as text with diffs.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `-diff` in your .gitattributes file. It should just be `linguist-generated=true`:

```
my_sub_directory/archive.tar.gz.part.* linguist-generated=true
*.json linguist-generated=true
```

Same as the example in [Customizing how changed files appear on GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/articles/customizing-how-changed-files-appear-on-github):

> For example, to mark `search/index.json` as a generated file, add this
>   line to .gitattributes:
>
> ```
> search/index.json linguist-generated=true
> ```

Though that doesn't really tell Github to "*track the files as binary*", it just "*keep certain files from displaying in diffs by default, or counting toward the repository language*". So in pull requests, it just does not display the diff *by default*:

[image]

Comment: I tried what you suggested and GitHub is still not showing the altered behaviour where it displays "Some generated files are not rendered by default". And when you say "not contribute to the repository language", do you mean it won't attribute the number of lines added by the flagged files?

edit 1: it seems to work for the JSON file but not the tar.gz. Give me a moment.

Comment: @AhmedSakr "_do you mean it won't attribute the number of lines_": I think it just won't be included in the repo metrics, such as the [colored bar at the top of repo home page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48055067/2745495) (which displays the % of each language) or the language tags for each repo in your profile home page.

Comment: @AhmedSakr "_but not the tar.gz_": Make sure the [git pattern format](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) is correct.